# Add elements to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["sort"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["day"]=>
        string(2) "2"
        ["month"]=>
        string(1) "8"
        ["year"]=>
        string(4) "2015"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["sort"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["day"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["month"]=>
        string(1) "8"
        ["year"]=>
        string(4) "2015"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["sort"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["day"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["month"]=>
        string(1) "8"
        ["year"]=>
        string(4) "2015"
      }
    }
```

As you can see it consists of sort, date, month and year. I want to add new element into the same array with value "day" +1.

If the 8th of august 2015 is in array the it should also include 9th of august 2015.
I need a way to extract values, calculate new date and put back in all dates.
The result should look like this:

```
array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sort"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["day"]=>
            string(2) "2"
            ["month"]=>
            string(1) "8"
            ["year"]=>
            string(4) "2015"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sort"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["day"]=>
            string(1) "5"
            ["month"]=>
            string(1) "8"
            ["year"]=>
            string(4) "2015"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sort"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["day"]=>
            string(1) "9"
            ["month"]=>
            string(1) "8"
            ["year"]=>
            string(4) "2015"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sort"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["day"]=>
            string(2) "3"
            ["month"]=>
            string(1) "8"
            ["year"]=>
            string(4) "2015"
          }
          [4]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sort"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["day"]=>
            string(1) "6"
            ["month"]=>
            string(1) "8"
            ["year"]=>
            string(4) "2015"
          }
          [5]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sort"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["day"]=>
            string(1) "10"
            ["month"]=>
            string(1) "8"
            ["year"]=>
            string(4) "2015"
          }
        }
```

Ideally it should also exclude new dates, if allready identical date is in the array.

Comment: This is probably a terrible idea. Look for existing date methods and/or libraries. Working with dates is notoriously difficult : http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create array with new items and merge it with old array

```
$temp = array();
foreach($array as $item)
   $temp[] = array_replace($item, array("day" => $item["day"]+1));
$res = array_merge($array, $temp);
```

To exlude repeating day

```
$days = array_reduce($array, 
        function($a, $i) { $a[$i['day']] = 1; return $a; ; }, 
        array());

$temp = array();
foreach($array as $item)
   if (! isset($days[$item["day"]+1]))
      $temp[] = array_replace($item, array("day" => $item["day"]+1));
$res = array_merge($array, $temp);
```

Comment: thanks alot. This works exactly like i need it to, but it returns "day" as an int. How i convert this to string?

Comment: php has no diffgerence between numbrer and numeric string.

Comment: I need to use output for javascript calender. I will try anyway to see if i works

Comment: Write it so: `array("day" => (string) ($item["day"]+1))`